# What is the meaning of a quantile regression model that predicts the conditional mean?

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation, quantile-regression

What does that phrase "quantile regression model that predicts the conditional mean"  mean? How to interpret that?

I found it in [Liu et al. (2020)](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/computingengineering/article-abstract/20/3/031003/1073961/A-Predictive-Analytics-Tool-to-Provide-Visibility?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

The authors have compared the results of linear regression, QRF conditional mean, QRF conditional median, QRF conditional first quantile, and QRF conditional third quantile. What confuses me is that for my little understanding, QRF predicting the conditional mean is exactly the same as Random forest, and the results for both should be identical, which is not the case in that paper! Note: the authors use R packages randomForest, and quantregForest.

Comment: This does not seem to make sense. The mean is not a quantile. (The *median* is, maybe it's a simple typo?) Where did you find this phrase?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Count me as another voice for getting a reference. A conditional median makes sense, but mean makes less sense. // What do you understand about the idea of linear regression predicting the conditional mean?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa and Dave
 I found this phrase in a paper that uses QRF. The authors have compared the results of linear regression, QRF conditional mean, QRF conditional median, QRF conditional first quantile, and QRF conditional third quantile.
What confuses me is that for my little understanding, QRF predicting the conditional mean is exactly the same as Random forest, and the results for both should be identical, which is not the case in that paper! 
Note: the authors use R packages randomForest, and quantregForest.

Comment: Hm. Can you add a link to the paper?

Comment: It must be this PLoS One paper: [A quantile regression forest based method to predict drug response and assess prediction reliability](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6173405/). They "make a small change to the right side of formula for the median" to estimate the mean.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa Here  is a link to that paper
https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/computingengineering/article-abstract/20/3/031003/1073961/A-Predictive-Analytics-Tool-to-Provide-Visibility?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @dipetkov 
With their change to the right side formula, i believe this is the exact formula used in Random Forest model to predict the conditional mean E(Y|X=x)

Comment: Thanks. I took the liberty of adding the link into your question. I don't have access to the paper, unfortunately. You could quote the relevant section.

Comment: @ahmedabdrahiem, the link does not work. It seems to be not just the access to the article. Also the main domain can not be retrieved. Could you update your question with more information about the context. The mean and the median are not the same thing (although they may have for some distributions the same value), so whatever the sentence means, a typo, an error, or maybe there is some logic behind it, must be seen from the context.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus, i have already modified the post.

Comment: @AhmedAbdalrahiem your post does not contain a lot of information that helps to interpret the phrase. The mean is not a quantile, so it is difficult to say what that phrase means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article *"A predictive analytics tool to provide visibility
into completion of work orders in supply chain
systems"* that you refer to is not very clear about it.

At some point they actually say the following

> As a generalization of Random Forest, Quantile Regression Forest predicts the conditional quantiles instead of the
> conditional mean

So it is a bit odd that they speak about QRF predicting the conditional mean.

But indeed, in the results section of the article they suddenly introduce 'QRF conditional mean'. They only use this term in four places (only in the results) and do not explain it.

---

A wild guess might be that it relates to how they perform the [bagging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#Bagging) in the random forests algorithm.

They explain how they obtain several regression tree estimates $\hat{y}_m$ and as a final result use the average of $M$ trees

$$\hat{y}(\mathbf{x}^\prime) = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M \hat{y}_m(\mathbf{x}^\prime)$$

Then they explain quantile regression forest as using a different cost function (the absolute error). But in addition it seems that they also use a different bagging method with an additional equation. If we fill in their equation 6 into equation 3, then we get

$$Q_\alpha(\mathbf{x}) = \text{inf}\left\{ y: \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M \mathbf{1}_{\hat{y}_m(\mathbf{x}^\prime)\leq y} \geq \alpha \right\}  $$

It could be that their 'QRF conditional mean', 'QRF conditional median', 'QRF conditional 1st quantile' and 'QRF conditional 3rd quantile', relate to the different bagging methods.

So it could be that this 'quantile regression model that predicts the conditional mean' relates to something like median of means or mean of medians.