# Prediction of mean in addition to quantiles using quantile regression in ranger

Tags: r, random-forest, quantile-regression

I am confused about the possibilities to predict the mean using quantile regression forests. In my understanding, quantile regression enables the prediction of the probability distribution, i.e. the prediction of quantiles. Some studies, however, use quantile regression forests to predict the  mean in addition to the prediction of quantiles, see [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580162/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-quantile-regression-model-that-predicts-the-conditional) and [study example](https://soil.copernicus.org/articles/7/217/2021/soil-7-217-2021.pdf).

R code for the study example (SoilGrids) has been shared, see [git page](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids/-/blob/master/models/ranger/predict_qrf_fun.R). Testing this concept on a sample dataset, it indeed seems that the mean can be predicted using a quantile regression forest (see code and visualisation below). My question is: does this make sense from a theoretical perspective? Or are there cases at which the quantile regression model will provide different predictions in comparison to the regular model?

```
#libraries
library(ranger)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

#load data
dt <- iris

#create ranger models (with and without quantile forests)
ranger.models <- lapply(c(TRUE, FALSE), FUN = function(x){
  ranger(
    formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width,
    data = dt,
    quantreg = x,
    seed = 123
  )
})
names(ranger.models) <- c("quantreg", "regular")

#predict on data
  #quantile regression model - mean
dt$quantreg_mean <- predict(
object = ranger.models$quantreg,
    data = dt,
    type = "response",
    se.method = "infjack"
  )$predictions

  #quantile regression model - median
dt$quantreg_median <-
  predict(
object = ranger.models$quantreg,
    data = dt,
    type = "quantiles",
    quantiles = 0.5,
    se.method = "infjack"
  )$predictions |> as.vector()

  #regular regression model - mean
dt$regular_mean <- 
  predict(
object = ranger.models$regular,
    data = dt,
    type = "response",
    se.method = "infjack"
  )$predictions

#visualize
dt.long <- pivot_longer(dt, cols = c("quantreg_median", "quantreg_mean"))
ggplot(dt.long, aes(x = regular_mean, y = value)) + facet_wrap(~name) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) + theme_bw()
```

[image: result]